# JetBrains - Android studio : No user option available in Editor>Live Template

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide, live-templates

I am following [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/tutorial-using-live-templates-in-todo-comments.html) guide from jetbrains :

For step  : **Creating live template and variables**

I am not able to find "user" option at Editor>Live Template.

Can anyone please help? I am using latest android studio version.

Answer (score 0):

user is an live-template group that is auto-created by IntelliJ when using certain context menus. There is no reason why you can not create your own template group, with your own name, or re-create the user template group yourself.

[image]